# Should the tag "incorrect" be banned on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

There are 10 questions on Stack Overflow tagged [incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incorrect). I don't think this tag gives any value.

Ban it?

Comment: Similarly 3143 questions tagged "error"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error

Comment: [error] tag does add value.  It denotes a question about origins of a specific error when you do X (not about how to do X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Banning is a bit strong here, but it's easier (much) for me to batch remove with a single command than have you guys do it all manually.

The exception is, in cases where each question containing the tag needs to be examined to see if the tag is in fact correct..

Comment: I went through them anyway. In some case, the tag was used because the title / error had simply been pasted into the tag field... So there were other helpful tags such as [is].

Comment: @shog9 hmm, some of the "is" uses are somewhat justifiable, but I'm killing them anyway as too ambiguous to be useful

Comment: you mean, for example, questions about the `is` keyword in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Ten uses in a year and a half? Why just re-tag them... It doesn't seem likely to become a problem.

Comment: Looks like it's already be done!